# Can ROC/AUC help model training or just be used for model chosing?

Tags: machine-learning

if can be used to help for training?how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer would depend on the model you have in mind. For something like multi-variate linear regression, you would use it for factor reduction. For something like a neural network, you could use it while you test different settings for any number of things like the dropout rate or the learning rate. It really just depends on what you're working on at the time.

Answer (score 0):

AUC-ROC curve is a model evaluation graph that clearly describes the capability of the model to distinguish between individual classes. It has nothing to do with model training directly but can help us set and tune the hyperparameters for our model.

If the model is capable of distinguishing the difference between the classes, the *AUC* is *1* and so on and so forth.

[image]
[image]

Read more about it here [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-auc-roc-curve-68b2303cc9c5).

Answer (score 0):

It's a non-differentiable metric so you cannot easily or scalably make a model minimize that metric as loss function instead of another one, same as you cannot make a model directly minimize something like classification accuracy.